# where to store Tenant user mapping in multi tenant microservices

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, multi-tenant

I am new to microservices , and currently designing a SASS based multi tenant application .
now i have 3 services , one for auth related activities , one for user ,roles and rbac and one for tenant  all the services have their own respective DB's.
now since its a multi tenant application. i am not able to decide in which DB do i store the tenant - User related mapping .
do i create a seperate tables for mapping tenets and store in the tenant service DB or do i take the tenant ID from the service and store the tenant related mapping in the user service Database .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Storing Tenant-User Mapping in Tenant Service Database:**
The tenant service becomes the source of truth for tenant-related data, and the user service can query the tenant service to get the necessary mapping.

**Pros:**
Ensures strong data isolation for tenants in the tenant service.
Simplifies user service by reducing its dependencies and complexity.
Minimizes the need for cross-service queries.

**Cons:**
Requires additional coordination between the tenant service and user service when creating, updating, or deleting user-tenant mappings.
Increases the dependency of the user service on the tenant service.

**Storing Tenant-User Mapping in User Service Database with Tenant ID:**
Tenant-specific operations can be achieved by filtering or joining the user data on the tenant ID.

**Pros:**
Allows the user service to work autonomously without depending on the tenant service for mapping data.
Can simplify certain operations within the user service.

**Cons:**
May require more careful data isolation measures to prevent data leakage between tenants.
Could lead to increased load on the user service if you have a large number of tenants or frequent queries for tenant-specific data.
Cross-tenant operations might be less efficient due to the need to filter or join data based on tenant IDs.
The choice between these options depends on the specific needs and priorities of your application. If strong data isolation and simplicity in the tenant service are essential, the first option might be preferable. If you want to minimize dependencies and potential performance bottlenecks in the user service, the second option could be more suitable.

In practice, the best choice depends on your specific use case. You can consider a hybrid approach where basic user-tenant mapping information is stored in the user service, but more extensive tenant-specific data is stored in the tenant service. You can also use caching mechanisms to improve performance, regardless of where the data is initially stored.